# Central margin definition for a button with Materialdesigninxaml style

Tags: xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I have a quick (and most likely) easy question for which I unfortunately do not find a suitable solution. My requirements are as follows:

- For the purpose of creating a navigation bar, I want to stack some buttons. For this purpose, I am using a stack panel.
- Between each of the buttons, I want to have some space. I could of course set the margin for every button, however I find this solution not very robust and instead want to define the margin centrally.
- What I therefore did is I defined a style within the stack panel and set the margin once. This works great with one issue: For the button I would love to use a style provided by Materialdesigninxaml. When I however set the style to the button, the margin style gets ignored.

Has anyone an idea or do I need to make use of a workaround?
Thank you guys for your help.

Here is my sample code which works as no Materialdesigninxaml style is defined:

```
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Database" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="BUTTON 1"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

This is my code with a specified Materialdesigninxaml style which does not work:

```
           <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Database" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="BUTTON 1"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```